# How to completely disable WebRTC in DotNetBrowser?

Tags: c#, webrtc, dotnetbrowser

Based on DotNetBrowser documentation there is posibility to customize WebRTC settings in browser. But theres no option to disable it, only to redirect all traffic to UDP proxy, this is the code they provide as example

```
browser.Preferences.WebRTCIPHandlingPolicy = 
    BrowserPreferences.WebRTCIPHandlingPolicyEnum.DisableNonProxiedUdp;
```

What this does is not disable WebRTC, but just redirect traffic to proxy, is there possibility to disable webRTC completely?

Reason is, many website recognize this and automatically ban accounts. If I run WebRTC leak test, it show that my webrtc is enabled, but IP is blank, which automatically ban me on certain websites, making it unusable.

Comment: nobody worked with it?

Comment: We will be glad to help you with your questions. Please contact us directly at customer-care@teamdev.com

Comment: Hey Natasha, I sent email